# Python Serial Writes slows down after some time

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port, pyserial

A Python 2.7 program on Windows 8 x64 constantly writes to the serial COM port (USB port) using pySerial. It writes about 30 lines then sleeps for 2-3 seconds and writes again. `write()` is called from within a thread.

**Problem:** After doing the writes for about 2 minutes, the serial writes starts to slow down to about 3-4 writes per second.

```
def write(self):
    print 'checkpoint A'
    payload = str(self.number) + 'H\n'

    print 'checkpoint B'
    self.serial.write(payload)

    print 'checkpoint C'
```

Using `print` commands, we notice that `self.serial.write()` starts to take some time to finish.

Why does the writes start to slow down after a while?

---

```
class CookingPart(object):

    def __init__(self, number, serial):

        self.number = number
        self.serial = serial

        self.switch = 0     # Off by default


    def toggle(self):

        if self.switch:
            self.close()

        else:
            self.open()


    def open(self):
        self.switch = 1
        payload = str(self.number) + 'H\n'
        self.serial.write(payload)


    def close(self):
        self.switch = 0
        payload = str(self.number) + 'L\n'
        self.serial.write(payload)



class Cooker(object):

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.active = False


    def toggle(self):
        if not self.active:
            self.active = True
            self.run()
        else:
            self.active = False
            self.recipeThread.stop()


    def run(self):
        # Start Thread
        self.recipeThread = RecipeThread(recipe, self.screen)
        self.recipeThread.connect(self.recipeThread, QtCore.SIGNAL("update(float)"), self.updateProgress)
        self.recipeThread.start()



class RecipeThread(QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, recipe, screen):
        super(RecipeThread, self).__init__()
        self.recipe = recipe
        self.screen = screen
        self.stopThread = False

    def run(self):

        # EXECUTE
        for layer in self.recipe['layers']:

            for i in range(layer['loop']):

                for ingredient in layer['ingredients']:
                    for i in range(ingredient['loop']):
                        for step in ingredient['steps']:

                            # Check if it should be stopped
                            if self.stopThread:
                                print 'Stopping'
                                self.stop = True    # reset flag
                                return

                            # Open/Close Part
                            for cookingPartNumber in cookingPartNumbers:
                                if cookingPart in cookingPartsToUse:
                                    cookingParts[cookingPartNumber].open()
                                else:
                                    cookingParts[cookingPartNumber].close()

                            # Wait
                            time.sleep(float(duration))

                            # Update Runtime
                            self.updateProgress(duration)

                print 'Cycle done.'


    def stop(self):
        self.stopThread = True


    def updateProgress(self, duration):
        # Emit SIGNAL
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('update(float)'), self.runTime)
```

Comment: Sounds like the serial buffer is filling up. What is it writing to, Arduino..?

Comment: @Drewness yes it's writing to Arduino. What should we do?

Comment: Could you add the entire class? If it's not like a bazillion lines long...

Comment: @Drewness I simplified the class to only the code that deals with the serial writes.

Comment: Fair enough. Where does `def write(self)` go in the class?

Comment: @Drewness `def write(self)` is actually `def open(self)` in the new class code of `CookingPart` I've just added

Comment: I thought so but wanted to make sure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49672/discussion-between-drewness-and-nyxynyx)